# Trying understand tensorflow sequential summary

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I can't figure out a summary of my model. For example first 2 rows of the summary(tf.keras.Sequential.summary()):

| Layer (type) | Output Shape | Param # |
| --- | --- | --- |
| zero_padding2d (ZeroPadding2D) | (None, 70, 70, 3) | 0 |
| conv2d (Conv2D) | (None, 64, 64, 32) | 4736 |

I don't understand why 4736 params? 64 * 64 * 32 != 4736

my model:

```
tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.Input(shape=(64 , 64 ,3)),
        ## ZeroPadding2D with padding 3, input shape of 64 x 64 x 3
        tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=3),
        ## Conv2D with 32 7x7 filters and stride of 1
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
            filters = 32,
            kernel_size = 7,
            strides = (1,1)
        ),
        ## BatchNormalization for axis 3
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(
            axis=3
        ),
        ## ReLU
        tf.keras.layers.ReLU(),
        ## Max Pooling 2D with default parameters
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        ## Flatten layer
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        ## Dense layer with 1 unit for output & 'sigmoid' activation
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
```

Comment: You are confusing output shape with parameters, they are not the same thing.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy looks like you are right but I still didn't get the difference. The parameter is what tensor flow gonna optimize thought the gradient descent.

Comment: How if we have 64*64*32=131072 digits we have only 4736 parameters for them?

Comment: under params I understand vector W and b

Comment: how I understand it, each digit has its own parameter. Then what shape of a[l-1] if current W.lenght + b.lenght = 4736

Comment: No, convolution parameters are not same as fully connected layers. It is (7*7)*32*3+32=4736

Comment: I see now! @Frightera thank you so much! Dr.Snoopy and Bas thank you to guys!

Answer (score 1):

The number of parameters equals the number of variables Tensorflow can tune when training that particular layer. It is related to the input size but does not equal the number of inputs directly.

That also explains the `param #` of the zero padding layer. Zero padding is not trainable, so the number of parameters is zero.

Comment: After applying Conv2D, we have 32 filters with shape 64x64. For me, that means 64*64*32 parameters for the next layout. How TensorFlow got 4736? Why rest of the parameters nontrainable?